# Unable to fit() a Scikit-Learn pipeline without being returned a ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need your help!

I've been getting a ValueError below when trying to fit my Pipeline.

```py
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,2].shape[0] == 1, expected 13892.
```

I've been tasked to build a model that combines the business_features of nursing homes with their cycle 1 survey results, as well as the time between the cycle 1 and cycle 2 survey to predict the cycle 2 total score.

This is my code that I'm using to accomplish the task above.

```py
# Creating a custom transformer to calculate the difference between survey
# 1 & survey 2 times
class TimedeltaTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, t1_col, t2_col):
        self.t1_col = t1_col
        self.t2_col = t2_col

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.col_1 = X[self.t1_col].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        self.col_2 = X[self.t2_col].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        difference = self.col_1 - self.col_2
        return difference.values

# Creating TimedeltaTransformer object
cycle_1_date = 'CYCLE_1_SURVEY_DATE'
cycle_2_date = 'CYCLE_2_SURVEY_DATE'
time_feature = TimedeltaTransformer(cycle_1_date, cycle_2_date)

# Using a custom column selecter transformer to extract cycle_1_features
cycle_1_cols = ['CYCLE_1_DEFS', 'CYCLE_1_NFROMDEFS', 'CYCLE_1_NFROMCOMP',
                'CYCLE_1_DEFS_SCORE', 'CYCLE_1_NUMREVIS',
                'CYCLE_1_REVISIT_SCORE', 'CYCLE_1_TOTAL_SCORE']
cycle_1_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst2', ColumnSelectTransformer(cycle_1_cols)),
    ])

# Creating my survey_model Pipeline object
# Pipeline object is a 2 step process, first a feature union transforming 
# and combining the business features, cycle_1 features as well as time   
# feature; followed by fitting the transformed features into a            
# RandomForestRegressor
survey_model = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('business', business_features),
        ('survey', cycle_1_features),
        ('time', time_feature),
    ])),
    ('forest', RandomForestRegressor()),
])

# Trying to fit my Pipeline throws the ValueError described above
survey_model.fit(data, cycle_2_score.astype(int))
```

Some additional context: I'm building this model to have its predict_proba method passed into a custom grader for a project. The grader passes a list of dictionaries to the predict or predict_proba method of my estimator, not a DataFrame. This means that the model must work with both data types. For this reason, I need to provide a custom ColumnSelectTransformer to use instead scikit-learn's own ColumnTransformer.

Below is additional code related to the business features and ColumnSelectTransformer

```py
# Custom transformer to select columns from a dataframe and returns the   
# dataframe as an array
class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        return X[self.columns].values

simple_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(simple_cols)),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
])

owner_onehot = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(['OWNERSHIP'])),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder()),
])

cert_onehot = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(['CERTIFICATION'])),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder()),
])

categorical_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('owner_onehot', owner_onehot),
    ('cert_onehot', cert_onehot),
])

business_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('simple', simple_features),
    ('categorical', categorical_features)
])
```

Finally, below is the full error raised

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-218-046724d81b69> in <module>()
----> 1 survey_model.fit(data, cycle_2_score.astype(int))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    350             This estimator
    351         """
--> 352         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    353         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    354                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    315                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    316                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 317                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    318             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    319             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    714     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    715         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 716             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    717         else:
    718             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    919 
    920         if any(sparse.issparse(f) for f in Xs):
--> 921             Xs = sparse.hstack(Xs).tocsr()
    922         else:
    923             Xs = np.hstack(Xs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    463 
    464     """
--> 465     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    466 
    467 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    584                                                     exp=brow_lengths[i],
    585                                                     got=A.shape[0]))
--> 586                     raise ValueError(msg)
    587 
    588                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,2].shape[0] == 1, expected 13892.
```

Further, the data and metadata can be gotten here

```py
%%bash
mkdir data
wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/providers-train.csv -nc -P ./ml-data
wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/providers-metadata.csv -nc -P ./ml-data
```

Comment: > This means that the model must work with both data types

Why not inherit the `ColumnTransformer` and overload the methods such that if it's a `dict`, it's converted to the appropriate DF first and if it's not a dict just maintain the behavior? That would be far less work

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand, where is the error being returned? @IanQuah

Comment: I'm not saying anything about the error? I'm merely suggesting what I think is an easier solution rather than defining your own `ColumnTransformer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing my TimeDeltaConverter seems to have helped.
Firstly by changing it to be a series of ints and then reshaping it to be reshape(-1,1).

```py
class TimedeltaTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, t1_col, t2_col):
        self.t1_col = t1_col
        self.t2_col = t2_col

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        self.col_1 = X[self.t1_col].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        self.col_2 = X[self.t2_col].apply(pd.to_datetime)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        difference_list = []
        difference = self.col_1 - self.col_2
        for obj in difference:
            difference_list.append(obj.total_seconds())
        return np.array(difference_list).reshape(-1,1)
```